# Mapbox GL JS layer animation low fps

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I use the following Javascript code to animate a radar layer on my map:

```
function updateLayer() {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(updateLayer);     

    var now = Date.now();
    elapsed = now - then;      

    if (elapsed > fpsInterval) {
        //fpsInterval being 1000 / 10 or 1000 / 60
        then = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);

        updateLayerImage();

    }

}
```

updateLayerImage() cycles through the radar images of the last 3 hours at 5 minute steps.

However this results in an extremely slow animation (around 1-2 fps). Here are the things I did:

- Since I'm loading radar images directly from an official weather source, each image being around 500 KB to 3 MB, I figured that this might be a bottleneck when loading them 60 times per second. So I wrote an independent script which caches the radar images of the last 3 hours on my own server, which provides a faster connection. Resulted in only little improvement.
- I changed that cache code to additionally compress the images to around 300 KB each, which should make it faster, but didn't help much.
- I'm not an expert in Javascript and wasn't sure how to "cache" images inside the client's browser, so I do the following: Once an image is downloaded I add it as a simple (hidden) img src="" id="" tag. Once my updateLayerImage() cycled back to the same image I do not load it again from my server but actually reuse the image.
- Mapbox GL JS doesn't support, however, updating the image of an image source but only its url which makes it download it again. So I downloaded the Mapbox GL JS code and changed the image source file to have a function taking an HTMLImageElement as a parameter and assigning it to the source without downloading anything. Yarn installed the code and embedded my own Mapbox GL JS file and there you go, no network connections happen after all the images have been loaded into the HTML page. Still not actually faster.

I'm out of ideas, since I have relatively small images, I do not load them from the internet more than once and reuse them. But still my fps is very low. I'm beginning to think that it's a limitation of Mapbox GL JS...

How to improve my fps?

**Edit:**
Measuring performance time of `updateLayerImage()` results in varying durations of 45 ms to under 2 ms! Inside `updateLayerImage()` I call Mapbox GL JS's functions inside the image_source.js file which fires a `dataloading` event, I assign my new image to its image variable and then I call _finishLoadinig() which fires a `data` event. Some of this image rendering magic - I think - takes a lot of time. Any way to simply reassign the image variable and trigger a simple re-draw?